# javascript graphing library

Tags: javascript, graphing

I'm looking for a nice graphing library for JavaScript that can handle the following types of graphs:

- Line Graphs
- Histograms
- Scatterplots
- Motion Charts

I've tried Google's Chart Tools but they don't seem to have a nice histogram chart (nor can I get their motion chart to work properly, even served off my Apache web server).

I'm hoping that there's a decent library out there that can support all of these, however if I must, I may include 2 different libraries (looking at Google Chart Tools, gRafael, flotr, and rgraph right now - none of which seem to include ALL of the requirements I have).

Comment: Heh, you listed all the ones I would have suggested.  You could also consider using more than one, with each covering a portion of your requirements list.

Comment: I'm trying to stay away from using more than one library - it'd be cleaner and easier to load into my site.

Comment: [Highcharts](http://highcharts.com/)

Comment: I would like to strongly suggest Highcharts - it has a lot of neat features and a really easy to use API.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm surprised no one has mentioned `JQPlot` yet. I'm not entirely sure it will do *everything* you need, but it's a very, very capable library. It's in jQuery, just to note.

[Demos of JQPlot here](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/)

JQPlot can fit all your needs, it seems:

- [**Line Graphs**](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/line-charts.php) JQPlot supports these just fine, as you'd expect
- [**Histograms**](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/bar-charts.php) Histograms are just bar charts, so that should be ok. A colour histogram would just consist of `1px` wide bars
- [**Scatterplots**](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/line-charts.php) Scatter plots are also fine
- [**Motion Charts**](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/bubble-plots.php) I think you mean bubble plots, which JQPlot also does

Comment: This certainly does look promising!  I have not used this library before (but am a fan of jQuery!) After some testing here, I'll see if this will fulfill my requirements.

Comment: I've had a look and it seems JQPlot does everything you want.

Comment: Still have some tweaking to do with a few of them - but it appears that this library is fully capable of supplying these types of graphs!  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Not a problem. Glad I could be of service.

Answer (score 3):

[graphael](http://g.raphaeljs.com/) supports a number of graph types.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571016/raphael-js-tutorial has some helpful tips.

Comment: I would most likely only use that library for the dot chart type, which acts as a motion chart (gives the user some idea of the "3rd" dimension of data based on size of the dot).  However, the "bar graph" they offer has no support of an axis, which seems rather silly.
On another note - I've considered using a bar graph as a histogram by minimizing the space between bars, but not too many libraries offer this detailed support.

Comment: http://hamiltonulmer.com/raphaelviz.html demos box plots with labels on both axes.  It's built on top of raphael js too.

Answer (score 2):

I ran across this question while researching the same topic.  Since I wasn't entirely happy with any of the options out there, I created [i3d3](https://github.com/eigenhombre/i3d3), a fairly simple library based on [D3.js](http://d3js.org) which may meet your needs.  So far it is working well for our project (monitoring system for a high-energy particle astrophysics project), and at least one other project in the wild.

Comment: I've used i3d3 with good success.  Although I'm hardly an expert on this topic I was impressed at how simple it was.